# Outlook Search in specific folders

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

How do I specify which folders I want to search in Outlook? I'm looking for something like,

```
from:foo@example.com folder:"Inbox, Archive"
```

Comment: No information at [MS search parameters](https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/Learn-to-narrow-your-search-criteria-for-better-searches-in-Outlook-d824d1e9-a255-4c8a-8553-276fb895a8da?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) or [MS search article](https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/Find-a-message-or-item-with-Instant-Search-c5d69ecc-9f0e-497a-8f4d-ceffed5c7ab8?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) +1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the "**folder:**" sytanx to search within specific folders:

**folder**: [folder name] [search criteria] 
or
**folder**: [folder name] **from**: [name]

Comment: Additionally if you want to search but exclude a folder (deleted, for example) it'd look like `... AND NOT Folder:"Deleted Items"`

Answer (score 2):

- Either press Ctrl+Shift+F or click the Find button.
- Open the Options menu on the Find pane.
- Select Advanced Find
- In the Look For drop-down menu, choose where you want to search.

If the folder that you want to search doesn't appear on the menu, click the Browse button and choose that folder in the Select Folder(s) dialog box, e.g. "Inbox", "Archive"

- Choose options on the three tabs — Contacts, More Choices, and Advanced — in the dialog box.
- Don't forget to click the Find Now button :)

P.S.:  The Advanced Find dialog box offers handy commands for dealing with items after you find them. Select the items and choose Edit --> Move to Folder to move the items into a new folder. Choose Edit --> Delete to delete the items. Type Ctrl+click or Shift+click, or choose Edit --> Select All, to select all items in the Advanced Find dialog box.

Comment: So is there no syntax to do this manually? For instance, I would like to be able to do slightly more complicated boolean searches (from:x OR from:y) AND to:z AND folder:"Inbox, Archive".... which is more challenging, if not impossible, via the GUI interface...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search the Archive folder (which in 0365 is a separate data file), you'll have to go to File | Options | Search and enable **All folders**.

Then you can go to Search tab (click in Instant Search to see that tab) | Search Tools | Locations to Search and click to toggle the check mark for each data file you have added to your account.

After all that, assuming you leave Archive checked, your search is run on those accounts with the normal filters you use for any search (know that Folder name is not the same as the data file name).

Hope that helps!