# Outlook 365 Search in specific folders

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, search, microsoft-outlook-2016, microsoft-outlook-365

I want to ask a similar question like this [one](https://superuser.com/questions/819716/outlook-search-in-specific-folders), but for newer Outlook versions.

Within an email account, I can search for specific messages which are in the folder with the name "folder name" with this command: 
`folder:[folder name] received:this year`

For example, if the folder name is "Sent", then the search text is `folder:Sent received:this year`

Now, I want to seach in the folders "Sent" and "Spam" at the same time with the same "received" criteria. What do I need to type into the search bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `OR`

```
example:
folder:[folder_name_1] OR folder:[folder_name_2] OR folder:[folder_name_3] OR folder:[folder_name_4] received:this year
```

Comment: it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to my research and test, this may not be able to achieve now. Yo you can use Ctrl + Shift + F to use Advanced Find as a workaround.